# Generate all combinations of various sub groups using a recursive CTE

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression, recursive-query

I need to generate all combinations of values as groups of records per group of records, including sets where group-records are excluded. I believe the way to achieve this is to use a recursive CTE.

Take the example of a 3 field table.

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_myTable(
   [id] INT NOT NULL,
   [group] VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
   [value] INT NOT NULL
);
```

With records.

| id | group | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 'A' | 5 |
| 2 | 'B' | 2 |
| 3 | 'B' | 6 |

Assuming that I am not aggregating at this stage I would expect 5 rows.

| id | group | sub-group | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 'A' | A1 | 5 |
| 2 | 'B' | B1 | 2 |
| 3 | 'B' | B2 | 6 |
| 2 | 'B' | B3 | 2 |
| 3 | 'B' | B3 | 6 |

This would need to work for an arbitrary number of combinations and could result in an arbitrary number of rows. I needs to work for 1 level of regrouping, though ideally should work for n levels of regrouping.

I tried this.

```
;WITH RecursiveGroups AS (
    SELECT 
        CAST(id AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS Grouping, 
        CAST(id AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS Ids, 
        1 AS Depth 
    FROM 
        tbl_myTable
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 
        CONCAT(rg.Grouping, ',', CAST(mt.id AS VARCHAR(MAX))), 
        CONCAT(rg.Ids, ',', CAST(mt.id AS VARCHAR(MAX))), 
        rg.Depth + 1 
    FROM 
        RecursiveGroups rg 
    INNER JOIN 
        tbl_myTable mt 
    ON 
        CHARINDEX(',' + CAST(mt.id AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + ',', ',' + rg.Ids + ',') = 0 
    WHERE 
        rg.Depth < (SELECT COUNT(*) - 1 FROM tbl_myTable)
)
SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Grouping) AS GroupId, 
    Grouping 
FROM 
    RecursiveGroups 
ORDER BY 
    Grouping
;
```

Which results in an error raised.

> [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]
> **GROUP** **BY**, **HAVING**, or **aggregate functions are not allowed in the recursive part of a recursive common table expression** 'RecursiveGroups'.
> (467) (SQLExecDirectW)

Comment: "*Assuming that I am not aggregating at this stage I would expect 5 rows.*" - can you add more details on what are you combining to get that output?

Comment: @lemon I am not currently able to produce that output. I would like to combine the group label, in this example 'A', 'B' with a number that produces a new group label, a sub-group; A1, B1, B2. Does that answer your question?

Comment: Where do you get that number from? Is it just an incremental or is it related to the "*id*" field?

Comment: would something like: select * from table t inner join table t2 ON t2.[group] = t.[group] do what you want?

Comment: @lemon that number should just be generated. Each sub group should have !n records which are grouped by combination. Each combination needs to be uniquely identifiable.

Comment: What is the number of repetitions of each record? (For example, because 'B' have two in this record, it must be repeated 4 times)?

Comment: @abolfazlsadeghi I just fixed the sub-group enumeration to reflect requirements. There is 1 group 'B' that has 2 rows which can be grouped !2=3 ways; B1, B2 and B3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want:

- all combinations, except groups with no members
- and you want those to be aggregated to one total value per combination
- and you want to use recursion

```
WITH
  enumerated (
    [group],
    [group_member_id],
    [value]
  )
AS
(
  SELECT
    [group],
    POWER(
      2,
      ROW_NUMBER()
        OVER (
          PARTITION BY [group]
              ORDER BY [id]
        )
        - 1
    ),
    [value]
  FROM
    tbl_myTable
),
  combinations (
    [group],
    [sub_group_id],
    [last_member_id],
    [value]
  )
AS
(
  SELECT
    [group],
    [group_member_id],
    [group_member_id],
    [value]
  FROM
    enumerated

  UNION ALL

  SELECT
    c.[group],
    c.[sub_group_id] + e.[group_member_id],
    e.[group_member_id],
    c.[value] + e.[value]
  FROM
    combinations   AS c
  INNER JOIN
    enumerated     AS e
      ON  e.[group]           = c.[group]
      AND e.[group_member_id] > c.[last_member_id]
)
SELECT
  *
FROM
  combinations
ORDER BY
  [group],
  [sub_group_id]
```

| group | sub_group_id | last_member_id | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 1 | 5 |
| B | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| B | 2 | 2 | 6 |
| B | 3 | 2 | 8 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/CtkWDthf)

You, can, however, avoid recursion all together, and just use bit-mapping...

- Demo showing all sub_groups' members as separate rows
- Just add a GROUP by if you want the totals

```
WITH
  enumerated (
    [id],
    [group],
    [group_member_id],
    [value]
  )
AS
(
  SELECT
    [id],
    [group],
    POWER(
      2,
      ROW_NUMBER()
        OVER (
          PARTITION BY [group]
              ORDER BY [id]
        )
        - 1
    ),
    [value]
  FROM
    tbl_myTable
)
  SELECT
    g.[group],
    s.[value]   AS sub_group_id,
    e.[id]      AS sub_group_member_id,
    e.[value]   AS sub_group_member_value
  FROM
  (
    SELECT
      [group],
      COUNT(*)  AS [size]
    FROM
      tbl_myTable
    GROUP BY
      [group]
  )
    AS g
  CROSS APPLY
    GENERATE_SERIES(1, POWER(2, g.[size])-1)   AS s
  INNER JOIN
    enumerated  AS e
      ON  e.[group]           = g.[group]
      AND e.[group_member_id] = e.[group_member_id] & s.[value]
```

| group | sub_group_id | sub_group_member_id | sub_group_member_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 1 | 5 |
| B | 1 | 2 | 2 |
| B | 2 | 3 | 6 |
| B | 3 | 2 | 2 |
| B | 3 | 3 | 6 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/kvIdE4Vk)

Answer (score 1):

There is probably a better solution, but here's mine.
We need to get all combinations of group / value for each group and give them a number.

```
CREATE TABLE #tbl_myTable(
   [id] INT NOT NULL,
   [group] VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
   [value] INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO #tbl_myTable VALUES (1, 'A', 5), (2, 'B', 2), (3, 'B', 6), (4, 'B', 12);

WITH TMP AS (
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [group] ORDER BY [value]) AS num,
        [group],
        [value]
    FROM #tbl_myTable
)
SELECT DISTINCT
    t1.[group],
    t1.[group] + CONVERT(VARCHAR, [t2].num) AS [sub-group],
    t1.[value]
FROM TMP AS t1
INNER JOIN TMP AS t2
    ON t2.[group] = t1.[group]
INNER JOIN TMP AS t3
    ON t3.[group] = t1.[group]


DROP TABLE #tbl_myTable
```

| group | sub-group | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | A1 | 5 |
| B | B1 | 2 |
| B | B1 | 6 |
| B | B1 | 12 |
| B | B2 | 2 |
| B | B2 | 6 |
| B | B2 | 12 |
| B | B3 | 2 |
| B | B3 | 6 |
| B | B3 | 12 |

Comment: close but not quite right. B1 - B3 (inc) should represent a single value. B4 - B6 (inc) should represent 3 pairs of values. B7 should represent all 3 values.

Comment: May I ask you to edit your exemple with the desired result ?

Comment: look at the accepted solution, you can run this with multiple input combinations to see the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

```
with _list as (
        select * 
        from (
        select  *, count( group_) over (partition by group_) as c 
        from ttt 
        )a
),
nums(n) as (
                select max(c) from _list
                 union all
                 select n-1 
                 from nums 
                 where n > 1
                )            
select * from (
select 
          t.ID
         ,t.group_
         ,t.group_ + 
         cast( 
case when ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by t.group_ order by (
select nums.n))<=(select count(*) from _list) then 
         ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by t.group_ order by  (select nums.n))  

         else (select count(*) from _list)
         end  as varchar(100))
         as [sub-group]
         ,t.value_ 
from _list t
join nums on nums.n <= t.c
)a
order by group_--, value_
```

| ID | group_ | sub-group | value_ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | A1 | 5 |
| 2 | B | B1 | 2 |
| 3 | B | B2 | 6 |
| 2 | B | B3 | 2 |
| 3 | B | B3 | 6 |

```
  create table ttt(ID int,group_ varchar(100),value_ int)
insert into ttt(id  ,group_,    value_)values(1,    'A',    5)
insert into ttt(id  ,group_,    value_)values(2,    'B',    2)
insert into ttt(id  ,group_,    value_)values(3,    'B',    6)
```

Comment: The result is close but incorrect. The sub-grouping enumerations should be distinct and their combinations unique. This query produces 3 sub-groups, there should be 4; A1, B1, B2, B3.

Comment: Thank you,i edited my code based on your expected